# Is there a command line utility for validating SQLite databases in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, sqlite, corruption

I am looking for a command line utility to validate SQLite databases. I ran into a situation in some inherited code where an application fails to startup because an attempt to access a database produced the following error:

```
database disk image is malformed
```

So I need to instrument some validation code in the application. Additionally, though, I need a tool that I can run from the Linux prompt to tell me simply if the database is corrupt or not.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's called `sqlite3`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
sqlite3 database.db "PRAGMA integrity_check"
```

Comment: exactly what I"m looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can use [**PRAGMA integrity_check**](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) on the database.

If the Database is corrupted you can use this SQLite command:

```
cd $DATABASE_LOCATION
echo '.dump'|sqlite3 $DB_NAME|sqlite3 new_repaired_$DB_NAME
mv $DB_NAME corrupt_$DB_NAME
mv new_repaired_$DB_NAME $DB_NAME
```