# how to fix my sqlite? database disk image is malformed

Tags: sqlite

When I did 'vacuum ;', just found message in below.

" database disk image is malformed."

So, I did like those.

`C>sqlite [malformed.db]`
 `sqlite3>.mode insert` 
 `sqlite3>.output a.sql`
 `sqlite3>.dump`

and continues...

`C>sqlite3 new.db`
`sqlite3>.read a.sql`

finally I found the new.db which file size is 0 byte.

any idea?

Comment: Restore it from the backup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a corrupt SQLite3 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259692/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-sqlite3-database)

Comment: same with me, I gave up finally.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this very process that you described, when the database is malformed adds one last line to sql file, which says "rollback" (-- due to errors, it elaborates).

Reminds some anecodes with genies, doesn't it?

While it is intented to prevent disasters when importing data on existing bases, it is a disaster if all you are trying to do is reconstruct your database from scratch.

So, remove this line, replace it with "end transaction;", re-run and you are hopefully ok.