# How to recover a corrupt sqlite database with journal and WAL files

Tags: database, sqlite, recover, journal, wal

So I have a Kobo E-Reader and accidentally deleted the reading database. 
The original file had an `.sqlite` extension and I managed to recover the database files.
When I finished recovering the files, I got a couple of `.sqlite-journal` files and `.sqlite-wal` files, but no `.db` file. 
[screenshot of the recovered files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOuMR.png)

I have basically no experience with sqlite whatsoever, as I've only used MySQL. 
I've been googling and looking things up about sqlite and how to recover this and as far as I know, the journal and WAL files are encrypted with a database key. 
But I have no idea how to get that key, or how to decrypt the files. I've installed DBBrowser for sqlite, but I can't get any further with that program.

Can anyone help me recover the database?

With kind regards, 
Edit: I have a `.sqlite` file with the database, while it doesn't have any records / rows / data, it does have all the columns, tables and required config stuff. Maybe I can use that instead of a `.db` file?

Comment: If you have no `.db` file, your data is gone.

Comment: Can you try to [recover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57872238/6843158) from the command line ? Provided you have a recent SQLite version (>= 3.29.0). I would keep a copy of that directory, do not alter the original any further. If you're in Windows, perhaps a Linux live CD would help. Not familiar with that software, but I suspect what you have is some sort of template database for first use (unpopulated).

Comment: @Anonymous I tried it and got the error 'Database is malformed'.