# How can there be duplicate rows with same primary key in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have the following SQLite db:

```
sqlite> .schema
...
CREATE TABLE history (
    date_created DATETIME,
    date_updated DATETIME,
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY ... ,
    ...
);
...

sqlite> SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('history');
0|date_created|DATETIME|0||0
1|date_updated|DATETIME|0||0
2|id|INTEGER|1||1
...
```

Even though the primary key is `id`, doing a query on it leads to duplicate values:

```
sqlite> select rowid, id, date_updated from history;
...
499|499|2021-03-12 18:45:46.433
500|500|2021-03-12 18:47:49.616
501|501|2021-03-12 18:47:50.322
500|500|2021-03-12 19:37:14.320
501|501|2021-03-12 19:37:15.153
```

Total row count also somehow 503.

How can this even be possible? I have a server running on SQLAlchemy to use this DB, if that makes any difference.

Comment: This is not possible. You are querying a table which does not have `id` as primary key.

Comment: @forpas I added `rowid` as well, it's also duplicated.

Comment: Execute: `SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('history')`

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with this. Restart your PC/Server and try it again.

Comment: Restarted, also tried reading the db from a new docker container with just the latest sqlite3 installed, no luck .. I think it somehow got corrupted by the software I was using "DB Browser for SQLite". After running the server again, it created a new entry, 502, and everything seems fine again from that point on, although 500, 501 are still showing as duplicated in the select query.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259692/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-sqlite3-database/57872238#57872238

Comment: Amazing, it's fixed. Thanks for the help!