# Sqlite file is not a database even for PRAGMA integriti_check

Tags: sqlite

I have this application using Sqlite db, but suddenly it throws exception saying file is not a database.

I tried .dump the old db to sql file. but inside the sql file still saying the error=>file is not a database.

Is there any other way that I can recover my data?
please advice. thanks very much.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQLite, as its name suggests is a lightweight SQL. Technically your database is stored in a file when you use SQLite, see: https://fileinfo.com/extension/sqlite

If your actions were already saved, then hopefully you have a backup that you can load it back from. If your SQLite database is in good state, but you want to generate a sql file, then you can use the dump command, see here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/

Comment: thanks for answering. the file is database.db, and when i want to load it using the DBbrowser, it showed error message saying that this file is not database. and i have already tried the dump command.  the sql file generated also saying file is not a database.

Comment: @Lancyliu can you connect to that file from the command-line?

Comment: i only can use sqlite.exe to open it. then when i try any sql command, it will say file is not database. like below. 
sqlite> .open database.db
sqlite> .tables
Error: file is not a database
sqlite>

Comment: @Lancyliu do you have a backup?

Comment: my application will do the back up only once a day in the morning. so the data from morning untill now only inside this database file. @Lajos

Comment: so i have to recover this one. do you have any advice? or do you know any tool that i can use to recover my data?

Comment: @Lancyliu maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259692/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-sqlite3-database/18260642

Comment: i tried PRAGMA integrity_check already. the same result saying the file is not database. and i tried the .dump command too. also saying this file is not a database.